# programmatically set initial view controller to tab controller swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, tabview

I have a tab controller on my iOS App and I want to check some conditions first and do as follow:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if condition {
        globalClass.token = u
        let mvc: MainViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! MainViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = mvc

    } else {
        globalClass.token = ""
        let mvc: LoginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as! LoginViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = mvc
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My problem is that when I programmatically set the initial `view controller` to first tab of the tab controller when it is loaded, the tab menus at bottom won't load. It just loads the `view controller` not tab menu.

MainViewController is the first tab of the tab view controller

Thanks,

Afshin

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to "Set the initial view controller"? Also, where is this logic in your project? AppDelegate?

Comment: And post the code in the "else" statement that doesn't work? This time edit your question and post it there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

`let tbc = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabbarStoryboardId") as! UItabBarController
 self.window?.rootViewController = tbc`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you I forgot to change the "tabbarStoryboardId" after altering my program. It was a dumb question :|